# How can we improve the quality of SQL questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, quality-improvement

In the review queues, I frequently come across answers that are simply code samples with no explanation whatsoever, and it appears that a disproportionate quantity of these are on questions tagged `sql`.  Looking at the questions, it seems that many of them are low-quality, showing little evidence of research or even understanding, and usually conforming to a standard help-vampire format, "here's my table; how do I select this line?", and lacking any indication of

- column datatypes
- indexes
- problem requirement
- any attempts so far, and why they are not good enough

There's already a good Meta question - [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](/q/271055).  I may start pointing questioners there in the hope of seeing constructive edits.  What else can we do to improve the questions?  And is there anything we can do to attract better answers to unimproved questions?

---

I'm not suggesting that SQL is the only area where low-quality questions abound and attract low-quality answers, but it does appear to be somewhere ripe for improvement.

I should mention that although I occasionally dabble in SQL, I'm far from expert.  But I can answer a simple question with both code and explanation.

Comment: This is very common with sql questions. I think that a large part of the reason is because so often developers are asked to handle the database side of their applications and many times they lack any formal training or experience with databases. As such, they don't have the knowledge to realize that posting the DDL is so important. This is a highly technical discipline that often gets thrown to people without the tools to handle it. Sad really but often databases are an afterthought for universities and companies. As a result....the questions are dreadful.